# Happy One Year Anniversary!

Tags: discussion

Happy Anniversary folks, its been a year since we are here. So time to light up candles and Divas to celebrate.

[image]

I know we have to buck up in [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) but as we have already completed a year together, we can clear other hurdles too.

Believe in yourself and keep walking righteous path and feel free to give feedbacks.

Comment: It seems there are only 8 active members on this site and in that only one who is answering (_everybody knows who is that_)

Comment: @Mr_Green, only 8? That's shockingly low for this topic. Why such low participation?

Comment: @EmacsUser initial enthusiasm has been decreased too much in the year. Thinking to cover it in my next meta post.

Comment: @EmacsUser maybe because most of the users are here to seek answers but not to answer. I admit that I am here to seek answers.

Comment: @Mr_Green true, answer seekers are always more in number than those providing answers. But ultimately it is the answer seekers who eventually become full-participating members of any forum like SX. For some reason that rate of participation is not happening here in Hinduism SX as it is on SX topics.

Comment: Congratulations to Hinduism SE for completing 1 year.

Comment: @Emacs User, I think most people do not tend to answer is because they haven't read the texts and are unsure of whether an event happened and if yes then on which line no. of which page of which book is it mentioned. There seems to be a lack of interest or time with people in reading original texts. Ofcourse, I agree that language in these texts is also bit tough to understand.

Comment: However, people should know that many a times, the answers or references to the answers or pointers to the answers for a new question might already exist in an earlier answer so they can make use of that and answer. If not then they can atleast comment about what they know about the question.so that others can get a hint and may be they can provide a better answer using that hint.

Comment: @Aby, true. You describe what is common to any knowledge domain and is not unique to Hinduism topic. Yet the participation rates are lower than other SX websites despite the vast numbers of knowledgable, educated, and highly competent Hindus in the world. I do not know if the precise problem is in participation or retention or both.

Comment: [Congratulations](https://media.giphy.com/media/GK7grZYLG7cs0/giphy.gif) for completing 1 year